# How add "--add-exports" compiler directive to Maven compilation

Tags: maven, kotlin, java-11, java-platform-module-system

I get the following errors when compiling with Java 11.

```
Symbol is declared in module 'java.xml' which does not export package 'com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.xni.parser'
Symbol is declared in module 'java.base' which does not export package 'sun.net.www.protocol.http'
Symbol is declared in module 'java.base' which does not export package 'sun.net.www.protocol.file'
Symbol is declared in module 'java.xml' which does not export package 'com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util'
Symbol is declared in module 'java.xml' which does not export package 'com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.xni.parser'
Symbol is declared in module 'java.xml' which does not export package 'com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.xni.parser'
Symbol is declared in module 'java.xml' which does not export package 'com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.xni.parser'
[...]
Symbol is declared in module 'java.xml' which does not export package 'com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd'
```

I need to specified `--add-exports` directive to the Java compilation.
I don't know how to add it to my Maven build compiling Kotlin code.

Also, I am not sure about the exact values for `--add-exports`.

This is my `pom.xml`.

```xml
    <!-- Kotlin compilation -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <source>src/main/java</source>
                                <source>src/main/kotlin</source>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Bundle a standalone JAR -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-all</finalName>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>DtdFinderKt</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Attempt to specify --add-export -->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>java11-compiler-java-with-kotlin</id>
            <activation>
                <file><exists>${basedir}/src/main/kotlin</exists></file>
                <jdk>[11,)</jdk>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <compilerArgs>
                                <arg>--add-exports</arg><arg>java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                                <arg>--add-exports</arg><arg>java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.xni.parser=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                                <arg>--add-exports</arg><arg>java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                                <arg>--add-exports</arg><arg>jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                            </compilerArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Comment: how about the format `<arg>--add-exports java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
`?

Comment: @Naman It did not work. Same errors.

Comment: Your configuration marked `Attempt to specify --add-export` adds the command line argument to the _maven-compiler-plugin_, but that only compiles Java source files. Are you sure it is them who depend on the internal code and not your Kotlin files? Also, it could be the compiler plugin itself that uses these internal APIs, not the code under compilation. In that case you need to add the `--add-exports` to the compilation process. For the Maven process, `.mavenrc` can do this (I think) - not sure how to do it if the compilation process is forked.

Comment: @Nicolai Yes API are use in Kotlin code. The project is only in Kotlin.

Comment: Basically I need to find the equivalent to --add-export for the kotlin-compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to include an annotation at the beginning of each source file using the internal APIs.

```kotlin
@file:Suppress("JAVA_MODULE_DOES_NOT_EXPORT_PACKAGE")
```

This annotation was found because of [this thread on Kotlin support forum](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/using-sun-awt-image-with-java-11/15127/5).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this compiler plugin to your kotlin-maven-plugin

```
kotlin-maven-allopen
```

Your pom will look somewhat like this after adding:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>test-compile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <args>
            <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
        </args>
        <compilerPlugins>
            <plugin>spring</plugin>
        </compilerPlugins>
        <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Official plugin documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/all-open-plugin.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing this excellent alternative.

Comment: Is this an alternative really? I think the above describes how to make Kotlin classes "open" aka "not final". This is usful when using something like Spring, which generates proxies and needs open/non-final classes. But the question was about Java modules, or am I missing something?